# Seeing a ViewController behind the displayed one

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to view the viewcontroller behind the displayed one? I have a viewcontroller with a scrollview, which has imageviews added as subviews and would like the view that presented this viewcontroller to be visible behind the presented view controller.

I have set all the views, the viewcontroller view too to have a clear color background, but still there is a black background. when I dismiss the viewcontroller, I see 2 layers being dismissed. one has alpha dropped, the other not.

Is there an easy way to make this effect possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Its not possible*. When a new view controller is pushed or presented as modal view, the previous view controller will be removed from the display(may be *UINavigationController/iOS* hides it). The rule is ***only one view controller would be visible at a time***. So you will see the *color* of your *window*(the *black color* you've mentioned) in the background.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a screenshot before displaying the other controller. and send this image to new controller to be displayed as background.

This will only work for static content, but you could do something like the curl display.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but the truth is what EmptyStack says.

You can use `setFrame` of the subView and add it on the `viewController`. Also use below method to set the index of the added View. By default currentView has Index 0.

```
[self.view insertSubview:myView atIndex:0];
```

or you can try below methods as per your logic

```
insertSubview:aboveSubview:
insertSubview:atIndex:
insertSubview:belowSubview:
addSubViews:
bringSubviewToFront:
removeFromSuperview:
```